Isometric action on matrix group
Consider the special linear group $SL(2, \mathbb C)$. Prove that the  group $SL(2, \mathbb C) \times SL(2, \mathbb C)$ acts on $SL(2, \mathbb C)$ via $(A, B) \cdot X = AXB^{-1}$ by isometries.
My attempt: Consider $M_2(\mathbb C)$ to be the set of $z \times 2$ matrices equipped with the quadratic form $q(A) = - \det (A)$. Let $b$ be the associated bilinear form; to find it, we will use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.
The Cayley-Hamilton theorem says that $$\begin{align}
A^2 -  \mathrm{tr}(A)A+\det(A) = 0 &\implies \mathrm{tr}(A^2) - \mathrm{tr}(A)^2 +2 \det(A) = 0 \\
&\implies \det(A) = \frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{tr}(A)^2 - \mathrm{tr}(A^2)),
\end{align}$$ therefore the bilinear form is given by $$b(X, Y) = -\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{tr}(X) \, \mathrm{tr}(Y)  - \mathrm{tr}(XY)).$$ Now, consider the Lie algebra of $SL(2, \mathbb C)$ $$\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb C) = \mathrm{Span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ hence $(SL(2, \mathbb C), b|_{\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb C\}})$ is a complex manifold:   $$b|_{\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb C\}} (X, Y) = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(XY).$$
Now, I cannot proceed further. Can anyone please help?

@DietrichBurde Thank you for the correction. I have edited.
